# Functions keeps returning with a type error of "nonetype"

Tags: python, function, nonetype

I have a assignment where I am to make a program that computes a resultant force. The thing is it works without the validation but when i started to input a validation function it keeps returning as a "nonetype" so the program can't compile

Code:

```
import math
def main():
    M1,D1 = get_values()
    M2,D2 = get_values()
    RFX = rx(M1,M2,D1,D2)
    RFY = ry(M1,M2,D1,D2)
    ResultantMagnitude = resultant(RFX,RFY)
    ResultantDirection = direction_r(RFY,RFX)
    display(ResultantMagnitude,ResultantDirection)
def get_values():
    print('\nPlease input the needed values for the resultant \n ')
    M = float (input('Magnitude of Force = '))
    M = validate_direction(M)
    D = float (input('Direction of Force = '))
    D = validate_direction(D)
    return M,D
def validate_direction(D1):
    while D1 > 360 or D1 < 0:
        print("Invalid Direction, enter again : ")
        D1=float(input())
def validate_magnitude(M1):
    while M1 < 0:
        print("Invalid Magnitude, enter again : ")
        M1=float(input())
def rx(M1,M2,D1,D2):
    #Force 1
    if D1 <= 90 or D1 == 360:
        F1x = ((M1 * math.cos(math.radians(D1))))
    elif D1 <= 180 or D1 > 90:
        F1x = ((abs(M1)* math.cos(math.radians(D1))))
    elif D1 <= 270 or D1 >180:
        F1x = ((M1 * math.cos(math.radians(D1))))
    else:
        F1x = ((M1 * math.cos(math.radians(D1))))
    #force 2
    if D2 <= 90 or D2 == 360:
        F2x = ((M2 * math.cos(math.radians(D2))))
    elif D2 <= 180 or D2 > 90:
        F2x = ((abs(M2)* math.cos(math.radians(D2))))
    elif D2 <= 270 or D2 >180:
        F2x = ((M2 * math.cos(math.radians(D2))))
    else:
        F2x = ((M2 * math.cos(math.radians(D2))))
    RFX = (F1x + F2x)
    return RFX
def ry(M1,M2,D1,D2):
    #Force 1
    if D1 <= 90 or D1 == 360:
        F1y = (M1 * math.sin(math.radians(D1)))
    elif D1 <= 180 or D1 > 90:
        F1y = (abs(M1) * math.sin(math.radians(D1)))
    elif D1 <= 270 or D1 >180:
        F1y = (M1 * math.sin(math.radians(D1)))
    else:
        F1y = (abs(M1) * math.sin(math.radians(D1)))
    #force 2
    if D2 <= 90 or D2 == 360:
        F2y = (M2 * math.sin(math.radians(D2)))
    elif D2 <= 180 or D2 > 90:
        F2y = (abs(M2) * math.sin(math.radians(D2)))
    elif D2 <= 270 or D2 >180:
        F2y = (M2 * math.sin(math.radians(D2)))
    else:
        F2y = (abs(M2) * math.sin(math.radi`enter code here`ans(D2)))
    RFY = (F1y + F2y)
    return RFY
def resultant(RFX,RFY):
    ResultantMagnitude = (math.sqrt((pow(RFX,2) + pow(RFY,2))))
    return ResultantMagnitude
def direction_r(RFY,RFX):
    ResultantDirection =math.degrees(math.atan((RFY)/(RFX)))
    return ResultantDirection
def display(ResultantMagnitude,ResultantDirection):
    print('\n')
    print('The magnitude of the resultant is {:0.2f}'.format(ResultantMagnitude), 'Newton')
    print('The direction of the resultant is {:0.2f}'.format(ResultantDirection) , 'Degrees')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

error:

```
  Please input the needed values for the resultant 

    Magnitude of Force = 200
    Direction of Force = 200

    Please input the needed values for the resultant 

    Magnitude of Force = 200
    Direction of Force = 200
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/IntelliJ/Python/Activity1/Test Force.py", line 78, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:/IntelliJ/Python/Activity1/Test Force.py", line 5, in main
        RFX = rx(M1,M2,D1,D2)
      File "C:/IntelliJ/Python/Activity1/Test Force.py", line 27, in rx
        if D1 <= 90 or D1 == 360:
    **TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'**

Process finished with exit code 1
```

the "D1","D2","M1","M2" keeps returning as a nonetype
it works when i remove the D1 = ,D2 = ,M1 = ,M2 = . but in doing so the validation will not overide the code

Comment: `validate_direction` and `validate_magnitude` aren't returning anything, so it's going to return None to the final call. This sets `D` and `M` to None in your `get_values`, and ultimately causes that error

Comment: @Chrispresso, that should really be an answer rather than a comment. See, I upvoted your comment and, other than some feelgood, you got nothing out of it :-)

Comment: i'm sorry for my stupidity but, why is it not returning anything even though I set the validate functions to override the vale of get_value

Comment: I'm really sorry, i'm really slow when it comes to programming i tried to input a return in the validate functions
def validate_direction(D1):
    while D1 > 360 or D1 < 0:
        print("Invalid Direction, enter again : ")
        D1=float(input())
        return D1
but it is still returning as a nonetype

Answer (score 2):

`validate_direction` and `validate_magnitude` don't return anything.
Take for example this:

```py
def add_to_my_list(my_list, val):
    my_list.append(val)

l = []
add_to_my_list(l, 1) # l now is [1]
```

This is adding something to a list, which was passed in (the reference to it).
If instead I did `l = add_to_my_list(l, 1)`, then there is no explicit `return` statement. In that case you are settings `l = None`, since the default return is `None` in Python.

If you want to modify a value within a function, you need to make sure it's an object that is going to get passed by reference (pass by object reference: https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/).

See this as an example:

```
In [375]: def modify(val): 
 ...:     val = 123.12312 
 ...:      
 ...:                                                                                                                 

In [376]: val = 5.1                                                                                                       

In [377]: modify(val)                                                                                                     

In [378]: val                                                                                                             
Out[378]: 5.1
```

`val` here doesn't actually change. So it's okay to do `return 123.12312` instead.

If you assign a value to the `return`, without actually having one, you get this:

```
In [379]: def modify(val): 
 ...:     val = 123 
 ...:                                                                                                                 

In [380]: val = 5                                                                                                         

In [381]: val = modify(val)                                                                                               

In [382]: val

In [383]: val is None                                                                                                     
Out[383]: True
```

In order to change `val` on the return, we can use the `return` statement since it's pass by value:

```
In [384]: def modify(val): 
 ...:     return 123 
 ...:                                                                                                                 

In [385]: val = 5                                                                                                         

In [386]: val = modify(None)                                                                                              

In [387]: val                                                                                                             
Out[387]: 123
```

For your `validate_direction` and `validate_magnitude`, you are going to want to return those values for two reasons:

1. The value passed in is being passed by value.
2. You are assigning something to the `return` of those function calls. Because the default is `None` in Python, `D` and `M` are being converted to `None`.

Instead, change it to :

```py
def validate_direction(D1):
    while D1 > 360 or D1 < 0:
        print("Invalid Direction, enter again : ")
        D1=float(input())
    return D1
def validate_magnitude(M1):
    while M1 < 0:
        print("Invalid Magnitude, enter again : ")
        M1=float(input())
    return M1
```

Comment: THANKYOU SOO MUCHHHH, I ALMOST CRIED WHEN THE CODE WORKED!!!!

WELP 4 MORE PROJECTS TO GOOO BUT I'M SURE THIS CAN HELP ME IN THOSE PROBLEMS

Comment: You got this :)